# Why thread in spring boot using ExecutorCompletionService does not start in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I use spring boot version 2.1.9.RELEASE along with Java 1.8 and have two lang running processes which I wanted to be started in parallel. Therefore I have decided to use thread.
 When I start the sumResult method, the second thread starts first and the first thread wait until the second one is finished.

**Why these two threads does not start at the same time or at least short after each other?**

```
private void sumResult(String year, String month, String day) throws 
    ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
         ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new 
         ExecutorCompletionService<>(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

         // First thread
         mut.initialise(year, month, day);
         boolean mutCompleted = completionService.submit(
               ()-> mut.sum(),true).get();

         // Second thread
         apt.initialise(year, month, day);
         boolean aptCompleted = completionService.submit(
              ()-> apt.sum(), true).get();

         // On completion of both thread
         if(mutCompleted && aptCompleted ){
              mixAndPrint();
         }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are blocking on calling `get()` on the first job before even submitting the second one.

```
submit
get
submit
get
```

If you want them to run in parallel, you need to do

```
submit
submit
get
get
```

Comment: Well, but this doesn't explain why the 2nd threads starts first? But I don't even know how that would be even possible.

Comment: I don't see how the second job can start first. It is not even submitted before the first job completes. Need @itro to provide some evidence of that.

Comment: but still straggling with blocking. let say if I do get for the first thread and the second is finish again I should wait for the first one to finish and then continue the rest.

Comment: The final goal is to know when both is finished and should be notified when both thread is done to be able to continue to other staff. Is there a way to know when both thread is done?

Comment: Each `.get` call will block/wait until its job is done. After you call `.get` on both jobs, they will be both done.